# ios ViewController lifecycle messed in use of ChildViewController

Tags: ios, scrollview, lifecycle, childviewcontroller

if i have two viewControllers: oldVC and newVC, when i perform 'oldVC.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller: newVC'

the iOS lifecycle in viewController transition system is:
`newVC ViewWillAppear`
`oldVC ViewWillDisAppear`
`newVC ViewDidAppear`
`oldVC ViewDidDisappear`

But when i Add  ViewControllers into a scrollView(sv) of the parentViewController, the lifecycle missed:
`newVC ViewWillAppear`
`newVC ViewDidAppear`
`oldVC ViewWillDisAppear`
`oldVC ViewDidDisappear`
because I `sv.addsubView(newVC.view)`
how to keep the right lifecycle

Comment: Waaaat? Absolutely no idea what you are asking about...

Comment: Can you please add some code so we can understand the problem?

Comment: sorry about my poor English ability  
if i have two viewControllers: oldVC and newVC, when i perform 'oldVC.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller: newVC'  
the lifecycle is :